# numpy 1.6.1 quadrature attributes for polynomial object not found

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am using python 2.7.3 and numpy 1.6.1. I am trying to obtain the gauss quadrature points for legendre and hermite polynomials. As per the [numpy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.legendre.leggauss.html#numpy.polynomial.legendre.leggauss), I should be able to access the attribute by typing

> > numpy.polynomial.legendre.leggauss(1)

But whenever I do this (even for hermite or hermite_e) I get an error

> > AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'leggauss'

What is going on? How can it be missing such an important attribute? I am using Mac OS X 10.7.4. Below is the exact code I type into python:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jul 12 2012, 11:58:31) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.61)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.polynomial.legendre.leggauss(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'leggauss'
>>> numpy.version.version
'1.6.1'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you click on [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/polynomial/legendre.py#L1662) in the documentation, you'll see the note that it was added in version 1.7.0.

```
def leggauss(deg):
    """
    Gauss-Legendre quadrature.

    Computes the sample points and weights for Gauss-Legendre quadrature.
    These sample points and weights will correctly integrate polynomials of
    degree :math:`2*deg - 1` or less over the interval :math:`[-1, 1]` with
    the weight function :math:`f(x) = 1`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    deg : int
        Number of sample points and weights. It must be >= 1.

    Returns
    -------
    x : ndarray
        1-D ndarray containing the sample points.
    y : ndarray
        1-D ndarray containing the weights.

    Notes
    -----

    .. versionadded::1.7.0
```

Comment: Great! But how do I get 1.7.0? I can't find it online anywhere. The latest I found was 1.6.2

Comment: `git clone git://github.com/numpy/numpy.git numpy`